# right align two flex containers

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm having trouble aligning two elements in a flex box:
What I want to happen is to have the "help" div to the very right then just left of that the "XX" div. I'm new to flex containers usually floating one elements right after the other would give the desired affect. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; 
}

#menuStrip {
   position:relative;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   height:36px;
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   background-color:black;
}

#menuContainer {
   position:relative;
   background-color:grey;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   padding:0;
   width:96%;
   height:98%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: flex;
}

#hh {
   position:relative;
   display:flex;
   align-self: center;
   font-size:14px;
   width:80px;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   height:50%;
   margin-left:auto;
}


#pp {
   position:relative;
   display:flex;
   height:70%;
   width:36px;
   align-self: center;
   justify-content: center;
   margin-left: auto;
   background-color:white;
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 1px;
   padding:0;   
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="menuStrip">
      <div id="menuContainer">
         <div id="hh">Help</div>
        <div id="pp"> XX</div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## JUSTIFY CONTENT

You are looking for the property value `flex-end` used in `justify-content`. Also remove the `margin-left: auto;` as it is not needed.

---

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#menuStrip {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
#menuContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 96%;
  height: 98%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#hh {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
}
#pp {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 70%;
  width: 36px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuStrip">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="hh">Help</div>
    <div id="pp">XX</div>
  </div>
```

---

## ORDER

To change the ordering like you ask in the comments, you will use the property `order`. It's pretty straight forward. The order default value of flex-items is `0`. You can either use negative or positive values, such as `-1`, `-2`, `1`, `2` etc.

You can either set this property in your first or second item, with different values depending which you prefer to change, they will both get the same result.

**Declaring it in your first item using a positive value:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#menuStrip {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
#menuContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 96%;
  height: 98%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#hh {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
  order: 1;
}
#pp {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 70%;
  width: 36px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuStrip">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="hh">Help</div>
    <div id="pp">XX</div>
  </div>
```

**Declaring it in the second one using a negative value:**

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#menuStrip {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: black;
}
#menuContainer {
  position: relative;
  background-color: grey;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  width: 96%;
  height: 98%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
#hh {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-self: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  height: 50%;
}
#pp {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  height: 70%;
  width: 36px;
  align-self: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuStrip">
  <div id="menuContainer">
    <div id="hh">Help</div>
    <div id="pp">XX</div>
  </div>
```

---

Simple order change interaction:

> **Note:** Clicking the anchor element will change every odd flex item's order to -1.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
a {
  font-size: 2em;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
  background-color: white;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  /* Default Value */
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.flex-container:target .flex-item:nth-child(odd) {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#flex-container">Change Order</a>
<section id="flex-container" class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

## FURTHER EXPLANATION:

`justify-content` property accepts 5 different values:

- flex-start, which is the default.
- flex-end
- center
- space-between
- space-around

---

### flex-start

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start; /* Default Value */
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

### flex-end

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

### center

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

### space-between

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

### space-around

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 30%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

**SUMMARY:**

[image: JUSTIFY CONTENT VALUES ILLUSTRATION]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  counter-reset: flex-items;
  background-color: peachpuff;
  display: flex;
  height: calc(20vh - .5em);
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  position: relative;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(2) {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(3) {
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(4) {
  justify-content: space-around;
}
.flex-container:nth-child(5) {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.flex-container::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  content: attr(data-justify-content);
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
}
.flex-item {
  counter-increment: flex-items;
  flex: 0 0 20%;
  background-color: gold;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}
.flex-item::after {
  content: counter(flex-items);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<section class="flex-container" data-justify-content="flex-start">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
<section class="flex-container" data-justify-content="flex-end">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
<section class="flex-container" data-justify-content="center">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
<section class="flex-container" data-justify-content="space-around">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
<section class="flex-container" data-justify-content="space-between">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</section>
```

---

## MORE INFO:

You can find more info in these resources:

[**Codrops**](http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/flexbox/)

**[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)**

**[Flexbox Cheatsheet](http://jonibologna.com/flexbox-cheatsheet/)**

**[Stack Overflow Michael_B's Flexbox Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/4305494)**

---

Playground:

**[Flexbox Froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)**

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, that's pretty close to what I want, however I just want the position of the XX and the help swapped. I'm assuming swapping the order of the html would do this however why is it ordered the way it is when the  help comes before the XX in the html?

Comment: Yes there is, I will edit my answer to try and help you even further since I got some spare time. I will as well include the ordering solution.

Comment: Ricardo that i'm playing that froggy game to help me learn more about flex boxes. What a magnificent tutorial!! thanks for that!!

Comment: Yes, it's a really nice contribution from Thomas Park.  I have edited my answer for you to check it out.