# Flex justify-content: center overwrite

Tags: html, css, flexbox, margin, center

I'm having an issue with flex and I have been giving it thought and don't understand what my code is doing.

So my goal is to center image and text using FlexBox. I used `justify-content: center` to center the containers on the x-axis and `align-item: center` to center the containers on the y-axis.

It works like butter except for when I collapse it. I implemented `flex-wrap: wrap` because I want the picture to drop down underneath, this works just fine.

But when I decrease the screen even further the text container for some reason skews to the left. It seems like `justify-content: center` is being overwritten. Can someone explain what is happening and how to fix this?

```css
#smaller-image{
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
} 

.parent{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  max-width:1000px;
  min-height:500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;

}

#aboutmetext{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  text-align: right;

}

#tryout{
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">MMB</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a>Contact</a><li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="parent">
  <div id="aboutmetext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita relinquet duas, de quibus etiam atque etiam consideret. Atque his de rebus et splendida est eorum et illustris oratio. Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne imperio, dederetur. Eam si varietatem diceres, intellegerem, ut etiam non dicente te intellego; Sint ista Graecorum; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Piso igitur hoc modo, vir optimus tuique, ut scis, amantissimus. At iam decimum annum in spelunca iacet. Sapientem locupletat ipsa natura, cuius divitias Epicurus parabiles esse docuit. Qui-vere falsone, quaerere mittimus-dicitur oculis se privasse;</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tryout">
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dqoqzoncd/image/upload/v1474214059/YzW4rUu_f69vph.jpg" alt="Manuel Martin" id="smaller-image"> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**CODEPEN LINK:** [codepen.io/mmartinb](https://codepen.io/mmartinb/pen/xEOmrR)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to this CSS rule (the right margin of 20px in there):

```
#aboutmetext{
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 20px 0 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  text-align: right;
}
```

You can simply create a media query that sets this margin to 0 as soon as the blocks are displayed below each other.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you defined a `margin-right` with a value of `20px`. This is affecting your layout when it wraps.

An alternative is to use `justify-content: space-around;` instead of center and remove the `margin-right`.

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
#smaller-image {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.parent {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#aboutmetext {
  width: 600px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
  text-align: right;
}
#tryout {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">MMB</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a>About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a>Contact</a>
          <li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>


<div class="parent">
  <div id="aboutmetext">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita relinquet duas, de quibus etiam atque etiam consideret. Atque his de rebus et splendida est eorum et illustris oratio. Claudii libidini, qui tum erat summo ne imperio, dederetur. Eam si
      varietatem diceres, intellegerem, ut etiam non dicente te intellego; Sint ista Graecorum; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Piso igitur hoc modo, vir optimus tuique, ut scis, amantissimus. At iam decimum annum in spelunca iacet. Sapientem locupletat
      ipsa natura, cuius divitias Epicurus parabiles esse docuit. Qui-vere falsone, quaerere mittimus-dicitur oculis se privasse;</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tryout">
    <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dqoqzoncd/image/upload/v1474214059/YzW4rUu_f69vph.jpg" alt="Manuel Martin" id="smaller-image">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[**Here's**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39430507/4305494) another answer I have provided that may help you better understand `justify-content` values, along with some useful flexbox resources in the more info section.