# How to swap two button elements using float in CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two buttons and I would like to swap them using float. How can I do it?

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Put `style="float: right;"` on the first one, and `style="float: left;"` on the second. Remember to put a `clear` afterwards.

Comment: just float the delete button to the left.

Comment: @Santi To which class should I add the clear property? and clear: both or right or left?

Comment: @AnkithAmtange I tried that but I am getting a space between the two elements which I want to get rid of.

Comment: Bootstrap's `modal footer` has a text align right property. You are missing a tag in the question. Is this what you are looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/waxza7zx/

Comment: @Marley Clearing is done as the final sibling to floated elements. So you would have your two buttons, followed by `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`. As far as having no space between them - can you shrink the `modal-footer` container? Floating an element to the right will force it to the right-most edge. By shrinking the container, the right-most edge would be closer.

Comment: @AnkithAmtange Exactly. That's the one which I am looking for. Your fiddle does what I want it to be done. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With additional CSS, you could float the `cancel` button to the right.

```css
.modal-footer .btn-default {
  float:right
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

#### `or`

You can use one of the helper classes on the first button --- [`pull-right`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" charset="utf-8">
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

You may additionally need to add a [clearfix](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-clearfix) depending on other content in the modal.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.right {
  float: right;
  }
.left {
  float: left;
  }
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="right btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="left btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

you can also use 
`order: 1` and `order: -1`

```css
.modal-footer {
  display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
  display: flex;
}
.first {
  order: 1
}
.second {
  order: 2
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="second btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="first btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

read [CSS order property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_order.asp)

Comment: How can I get rid of the space between the two buttons and align the delete button exactly infront of the cancel button. (right aligned)?

Comment: when you use floats it will throw each element to the furthest side, if the wrapper is a block element then it will be on opposite sides of the page. an easier way to re-arrange by `order: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Using `flexbox`:

You can use the `flexbox` property `order`. Like the property name suggests, it **changes the order of flex-items**.

---

More info **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430472/right-align-two-flex-containers/39430507#39430507)**.

---

### Code Snippet:

```css
.modal-footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.modal-footer .btn:last-of-type {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's the exact code which I implemented before. But I want to get rid of the flex layout and implement float because it's giving me problems with the tab indexing.