# CSS justify-content: space-between not being recognized

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am very new to html and css. I do know that in my text editor (brackets) the text changes color for keywords, but the "space-between" is not being recognized despite it being one of the choices. The other ones work. (like "center")

Basically what i'm trying to do is spread out my 3 images horizontally across the page when the page is at least 768px. Here is a portion of my index:

```
<main class="main-area">
    <section class="box">
        <article class="boxes">
            <a href="#">
            <figure class="featured-image">
                <img src="images/single-blue.jpg">

                <div class="box-text">
                    <h2 class="box-title">Blue Firework</h2>


                    <p class="box-blurb">Image subtext</p>
                </div>
            </figure></a>
        </article>


        <article class="boxes">
            <a href="#">
            <figure class="featured-image">
                <img src="images/single-purple.jpg">

                <div class="box-text">
                    <h2 class="box-title">Purple Firework</h2>


                    <p class="box-blurb">Image subtext</p>
                </div>
            </figure></a>
        </article>


        <article class="boxes">
            <a href="#">
            <figure class="featured-image">
                <img src="images/single-orange.jpg">

                <div class="box-text">
                    <h2 class="box-title">Orange Firework</h2>


                    <p class="box-blurb">Image subtext</p>
                </div>
            </figure></a>
        </article>
    </section>
</main>
<!-- Close the main section -->
```

I think normally people combine their stylesheets but my teacher wants me to do them separate. Here is a css file:

```
    /*
primary style sheet
*/
@import url('CSS/accessibility.css');
@import url('CSS/reset.css');
@import url('CSS/typography.css');
@import url('CSS/navigation.css');
@import url('CSS/masthead.css');
@import url('CSS/banner.css');
@import url('CSS/boxes.css');
@import url('CSS/levels.css');
```

here is another css file:

```
    /******** Boxes Stylesheet ********/
.box{
    margin: 0 0 1em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.box img {
    border: 2px solid #000;
}

.box-title {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: black;
    padding: 0;
}
.box p {
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}

.box a {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: .25em;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .boxes {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .box {
        width: calc(33.333333% - .5em);
    }
}
```

The text is white (not recognized) after justify-content: and also after Flex-wrap:

Thank you for your time. (first post so tell me if I posted wrong)

Comment: All those style sheets are hurting my eyes.

Comment: Purin - Is it Jigglypuff? :)

Comment: Consider adding a working demo, so the problem can be reproduced. You can use a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), or a third-party IDE such as jsfiddle.net or codepen.io.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selectors are inverted in the CSS media query.

Change:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .boxes {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .box {
        width: calc(33.333333% - .5em);
    }
}
```

For:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .box {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .boxes {
        width: calc(33.333333% - .5em);
    }
}
```

---

**Code Snippet:**

```css
/******** Boxes Stylesheet ********/

.box {
  margin: 0 0 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
.box img {
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
.box-title {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: black;
  padding: 0;
}
.box p {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.box a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: .25em;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .box {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .boxes {
    width: calc(33.333333% - .5em);
  }
}
```

```html
<main class="main-area">
  <section class="box">
    <article class="boxes">
      <a href="#">
        <figure class="featured-image">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2 class="box-title">
                                Blue Firework
                            </h2>
            <p class="box-blurb">
              Image subtext
            </p>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="boxes">
      <a href="#">
        <figure class="featured-image">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2 class="box-title">
                                Purple Firework
                            </h2>
            <p class="box-blurb">
              Image subtext
            </p>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </article>

    <article class="boxes">
      <a href="#">
        <figure class="featured-image">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
          <div class="box-text">
            <h2 class="box-title">
                                Orange Firework
                            </h2>
            <p class="box-blurb">
              Image subtext
            </p>
          </div>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </article>
  </section>

</main>
<!-- Close the main section -->
```

---

Not every editor is updated with the latest keywords, don't worry `space-between` is a valid CSS value for `justify-content` property. You can check out the accepted values for `justify-content` **[here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#justify-content-property)** and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430472/right-align-two-flex-containers/39430507#39430507).

Comment: @TylerH Done, thanks for the suggestion, you are correct.